# Hp laptop recovery error

Tags: windows, laptop, memory, laptop-repair

I have an hp pavilion dv6000 laptop that gives me this error 0x000000f when starting up. So I tried to reinstall windows using the recovery partition and that makes it to 11% recovery and then freezes and wont go any farther.

I have tried memtest and Ive tried booting with only half the memory but it still doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess your hard drive is faulty; as you're already doing a reformat you can just buy a new drive! There is software which will test it for you (I won't recommend any as it's off topic here), just search Google for SMART test or hard drive test.

Comment: right on! tried booting with a know good drive and it works fine